# How to batch and Unbatch agents based on the same value of parameter

Tags: anylogic

I am building simulation model for collection process. The problem I am facing is we have invoices arriving on daily basis. These invoices needs to be combined into single agent based on the account ID .  And then needs to be allocated to different people ( 10 Resources ) . I created code based on the answer for other question
[Anylogic: how to Batch agents with similar parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911476/anylogic-how-to-batch-agents-with-similar-parameters/68917002#68917002)

But the challenge I have is my batch size is not constant and varies based on the no of invoices received for any account . Below is the code I used but the batch is not created as expected. I just tried to use the same code for my problem.  Could you please point out what is wrong here.

I want to un batch these invoice after it is allocated to resource.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < wait.size(); i ++){
    Invoice invoice = wait.get(i);
    int ID = invoice.Account_ID;
    if (!productsWaiting.containsKey(ID)) productsWaiting.put(ID, new ArrayList<Invoice>());
    productsWaiting.get(ID).add(invoice);
    
    //Check the batch size if sufficient we release it
    if (productsWaiting.get(ID).size() > 1) {
        for (Invoice p:productsWaiting.get(ID)) {
            wait.free(p);
        }
        return; // we exit the loop since we have released a batch
    } 

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i ++) {
    if (productsWaiting.get(i) == null) continue;
    for (Invoice p:productsWaiting.get(i)) {
        wait.free(p);
    }
    batch.set_batchSize(productsWaiting.get(i).size()); //Since the batch is less than the standard we need to change it to what ever we are releasing
    return; // we exit the loop since we have released a batch
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can unbatch a batch using the unbatch block from the PML library, but only if you deselected the permanent batch from the batch block

[image]

I cant see anything wrong with your code. Can you please advise what is the actual behavior vs the expected behavior? This code will only release a single batch at a time. That is why in the original question you need to call this function at the `On Exit` code of the Batch block.

Comment: I am expecting that Invoices for the same account should get clubbed together and then it should get unbatched after service block.  Batch Size should change depending on the Invoice . Let's say in the Wait area we have invoices  with account ID like this . [ 1- A, 1-A, 1,-A, 2-B, 2-B, 2-B] I want to club this into batches  Batch1- Account ID A and Batch 2-Account  B

Comment: And what are you experiencing. Can you traceln what the output is?

Comment: Maybe create a new agent you can use as the batch agent and add a list of all the agents you batch to it to double-check if batches are being created correctly