# Batching out of a queue based on matching parameters

Tags: anylogic

I have agents entering a queue. The goal is to batch them based on a common agent parameter value and the batch size (which is dynamic). So, if batch size is 9, then the first 9 agents in the queue with the same value of agent.sortingParameter should be removed from the queue and added to the current batch, so it can be passed on to the next block.

[image]

In batchJobs/"On enter:" I have written the following code. However, I'm stuck. How do I add the agents I'm removing from the preceding queue to the current batch agent?

```
// Identify the store of the first order in the queue
Store targetStore = agent.pCustomer.pStore;

// Create an ArrayList to temporarily hold orders for this batch
ArrayList<Order> selectedOrders = new ArrayList<>();

// Iterate over the queue (not removing agents yet, just identifying them)
for (int i = 0; i < qAvailableJobs.size() && selectedOrders.size() < batchJobs.batchSize; i++) {
    Order currentOrder = (Order)qAvailableJobs.get(i);
    if (currentOrder.pCustomer.pStore == targetStore) {
        selectedOrders.add(currentOrder);
    }
}

// Remove the selected orders from the main queue and add them to the OrdersBatch agent
for (Order o : selectedOrders) {
    qAvailableJobs.remove(o);
    //HOW DO I ADD THE REMOVED AGENTS TO THE BATCH AND PASS TO ON ADD?;
}
```

I've tried this code in place of the final line above, but 'batch cannot be resolved to a variable.' I don't think batches are accessible either in 'On enter', so this approach likely won't work. What else can I try?

```
    this.batchJobs.onAdd(o, batch);
```

Comment: Found this post asking a similar question after I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911476/anylogic-how-to-batch-agents-with-similar-parameters

Comment: check this out:
https://noorjax.com/2019/07/02/dynamic-batches/